# Reading core loss graph of an inductor core

Tags: inductor, loss, core

The question is somehow unrelated but I hope someone answers,

[image]

From the above graph, how can I get the value of 0.3T line @ 25kHz ? The scales in the axes confused my mind.

Comment: Well, around 200(kW/m^3)

Comment: @G36 is this representation something standart? What should I search to understand how it works?

Comment: It is a base 10 log scale and they are quite popular in EE.